# Нейросети для отделения разнородных по природе данных по признаку гармоничности

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, данные

Сразу прошу меня простить - в нейросетях я махровый чайник. Только ограниченные начальные знания. И тем не менее, есть вопрос...

**Вопрос:** допустим у нас есть ряд данных, изменяющихся гармонически: простая функция "чет-нечет", тригонометрическая функция синуса/косинуса, набор простых и инверсных изображений, гармонически-изменяемые фигуры игры "Жизнь" ... Есть ли способ обучить нейросеть выявлять "гармоничность" на произвольном наборе данных? И если "да", то как?

Answer (score 2):

Давайте немного уточнимся, чего вам надо.
Есть данные. Вы написали, что они "гармоничны". Вопрос - вы ЗАРАНЕЕ знаете, что они гармоничны? Если да - то что вы хотите узнать нового.

А вот если нет, просто есть данные и надо ответить, есть-ли в них некоторая периодичность, то да такие методы есть. Например - анализ автокорреляционных функций, который может показать присутствие в ряду даже нескольких "сезонных составляющих". Есть и несколько других методов -  да то-же разложение в ряд Фурье и исследование его коэффициентов. Это задачи вполне "алгоритмические" или около того, и стрелять по ним из нейросетей особой необходимости нет.

Если я неверно понял ваш вопрос - тогда прошу меня простить и уточнить его постановку.

Comment: Нет, заранее не известно есть ли гармонические повторения. Это и нужно выявить.

Comment: Ну, тогда простейший путь - анализ авторорркляционной функции. Гууглите тему "выявление сезонности во временных рядах".

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Я взял тайм-аут на осмысление ... И все же??? Вопрос именно о нейросетях!

Мы многого можем "иными способами", возможно более рациональными, а возможно рациональными на первый взгляд! Меня же интересует - сабж! И это не практический вопрос, это для осознания/размышления.

Comment: Ну тогда вам надо напрячься, набрать тысяч 10 примеров "функций с сезонностью и функций без сезонности, на этих данных обучить  какую-нибудь нейросеть, способную решать задачи классификации, т.е. разбиения множества объектов на два класса, а при решении задачи каждый раз думать о том, что точность ответа может быть весьма далека от 99%.  И зачем все это, когда ответ на вопрос можно получить одним оператором?